# ROS electric installation problem

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ros-electric-desktop, but I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-desktop : Depends: ros-electric-eigen (= 1.6.0-s1323568233~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1323588691~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1323568273~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-visualization (= 1.6.7-s1323575414~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.2-s1323584064~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1323607694~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1323607993~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-robot-model (= 1.6.3-s1323571492~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1323609388~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-geometry (= 1.6.1-s1323568421~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-electric-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1323573853~natty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Any idea how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12440/ros-electric-installation-problem/) by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an apt problem, you should be able to clean up by doing the following:

First try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Which prunes any dependencies that were installed automatically, but might not be correct.  If that doesn't work, move on to:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which will finish any broken or cut-off installs and fix unmet dependencies.  If that doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

Which cleans up apt's working directories.

Those will generally fix all apt problems that you may have, remember to always `sudo apt-get update` before beginning to install anything.

**Edit: Possible Duplicates**

- http://answers.ros.org/question/3237/unmet-dependencies-when-install-ros-electric

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on 2011-12-23**:
Hi, thanks for the answer. I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've fought with this a few times recently, too. I've done the following in no particular order on a few machines and distributions, for both electric & diamondback:

- Completed forgotten half-finished distro upgrades
- Reviewing what's in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
- Using aptitude install instead of apt-get install (you'll need to install aptitude first)
- Uninstalling and re-installing with apt-get
- Remembering to run apt-get update first

On my end, these errors seem to be correlated with upgrading a distro, then upgrading ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1